holder.js has 'global is undefined' error
When I tried to use holder image within the below code:
import { run as runHolder } from "holderjs/holder";
import React, { Fragment, useEffect } from "react";
import { Image } from "react-bootstrap";

export default function HolderExample() {
  useEffect(() => {
    runHolder("image-class-name");
  });
  return (
    <Fragment>
      <Image
        className="image-class-name"
        roundedCircle
        src="holder.js/20x20?text=J&bg=28a745&fg=FFF"
      />
    </Fragment>
  );
}

I have the following error:
Uncaught TypeError: global is undefined
    newEl holder.js:2275

Thank you for your advice in advance.
The code is from -
https://github.com/imsky/holder/issues/225#issuecomment-770261030
